# How to read with SQL from DB2 using pyspark?

Tags: sql, pyspark, db2

I want to connect and read from from DB2 using an SQL statement with pySpark. The only code I found on the internet reads the entire table as below

```
user = <username>
password = <password>
jdbcURL = "jdbc:db2://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:50000/Database" 
prop = {"user":user, "password":password, "driver":"com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver",  "sslConnection":"false"} 
table = <schema.table>
df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=jdbcURL,table=table,properties=prop) 
df.count()
```

I would like to read using an SQL statement like

```
 'select * from table limit 100'
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like below in `Pyspark` to read from any `JDBC` source

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').option('url', '{}:{}/{}'.format(domain, port, dbname)).option('driver', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver').option('dbtable', '(select * from `{}`) as `{}`'.format(table, table)).option('user', username).option('password', password).load()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work with a slight variation of this                                                 
                                                                                                                                 
        df = (sqlContext.read.format('jdbc')
      .option('url', 'jdbc:db2://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:50000/myDatabase')
      .option('driver', 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver')
      .option('dbtable', "(SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable limit 100) as t")
      .option('user', user).option('password', password).load())
       df.count()

Answer (score 1):

Based on the response by @User12345 this was done as

```
df = (sqlContext.read.format('jdbc') .option('url', 
    'jdbc:db2://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:50000/myDatabase') .option('driver', 
    'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver') .option('dbtable', "(SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable 
     limit 100) as t") .option('user', user).option('password', password).load()) 
df.count()
```