# Any pyspark example to connect db2 blu db?

Tags: pyspark, db2

Looking for a db2 blu connection using pyspark. I want to load some csv data to a db2 blu db table.

Comment: [JDBC to other databases](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)?

Comment: What do you have tried? Have you search Stack Overflow, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952316/how-to-read-with-sql-from-db2-using-pyspark/51962165